# form submits before validation in php

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form which I want to submit, so when I click on submit it goes to the selectorpage.php and finds the selected function type e.g. login in this, which further calls the controller to execute the function. Issue I have is that there is a function called validateForm() in js, as soon as I click the submit button, it goes to the selectorPage.php. I wanted to stop the form submission, perform validation through js and then submit the form from there, I used onsubmit = return false; in form tag but it just blocks the form of doing anything further. And I also don't know how to redirect the form to the selectorPage if it somehow works in js. So anybody would like to give me an idea how to submit form from js and then redirect that page to selectorPage.php. Thanks

```
<form method="post" action="selector.php?type=login" id="login" id="loginForm">
      <div class="row">
           <div class="offset1 span1">            
                <div class="lbel">
                     <label class="control-label" for "loginName">
                          Username/Email
                     </label>
                </div>
                <div class="lbl_inpuCnt">
                      <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="loginName"
                             name="loginName" maxlength="50"/>
                </div>
                <div id="usernameError">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="lbel">
                      <label class="control-label" for="loginPassword">
                             Password
                      </label>
                </div>
                <div class="controls">
                       <input type="password" class="input-xlarge" 
                               id="loginPassword" name="loginPassword" 
                                maxlength="50"/>
                </div>
                <div id="passwordError">&nbsp;</div><br/>
            </div>
       </div>
       <div style="margin-left: 55px;">
           <input class="btn" style="width: 80px;" type="reset" 
                    name="reset" value="Reset"/>
           <input class="btn" style="width: 80px;" type="submit" 
                    name="submit" value="Login" onclick="validateForm();"/>
       </div>
 </form>
```

this is the javascript according to the code above

```
function validateForm(){
    form = document.forms['loginForm'];
    if(document.getElementById('loginName').value == "")
        document.getElementById('usernameError').innerHTML = 'Invalid username or email';
    else{
        document.getElementById('usernameError').innerHTML = "&nbsp";      
    form.submit();
    }
} //suppose it for the email validation only for the time being
```

Comment: It would help us if you could add the javascript function validateForm() so we can see what's happening there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the canonical way using inline event handling - see further down how it could be made unobtrusive. Also only have ONE id on the form tag, also NEVER call anything `submit` in a form it is a reserved word and will block submitting by script (which is what you tried to do)

```
<form id="loginform" ... onsubmit="return validate(this)">

<div style="margin-left: 55px;">
  <input class="btn" style="width: 80px;" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" onclick="clearFields()"/>
  <input class="btn" style="width: 80px;" type="submit"  value="Login" />
</div>
</form>
```

this is the javascript

```
function validateForm(form){ // passing form object
  document.getElementById('usernameError').innerHTML = ""; // reset

  if (form.loginName.value == "") {
    document.getElementById('usernameError').innerHTML = "Invalid username";
    return false;
  }
  return true;// allow submission
}
```

---

Alternative

```
<form id="loginform" ..... No event handler here ...>
```

Script:

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("loginform").onsubmit=function() {
    document.getElementById('usernameError').innerHTML = ""; // reset

    if (this.loginName.value == "") { // notice the "this"
      document.getElementById('usernameError').innerHTML = "Invalid username";
      return false;
    }
    return true;// allow submission
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could try

```
<form ... onsubmit="return validateForm();"
```

in the `validateForm()` function use

```
return true / false
```

depending if errors are found.

Comment: Exactly. Just to point out that `onsubmit` goes into the `<form>` tag

Comment: And for good measure pass the form object in the call rouse unobtrusive event handling

Comment: well the issue is, it does the work that it validates the form as was happening in my case as well, but still it submits the form. The thing I guess I need to handle is to submit form after validation via javascript which is not submitting, if I use button type as Submit it automatically sends the form without waiting for validation and if I use type button and call the function it still doesn't submit the form from javascript I am using this simple line to submit in js                          [code]form = document.forms['formID']; form.submit();[/code]

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues to this in the past myself.

When you click the 'Login' button of your form, you are triggering two separate events - Calling of the 'validateForm();' javascript function, and submission of the form itself. The problem here, is that submitting the form involves the browser sending an outbound request back to the form target, and to my knowledge, there is no way, using javascript, to kill a request event once it has been triggered.

Using 'onsubmit=return false;', likely, is doing exactly what it is supposed to do - Exiting the current javascript scope (and therefore preventing further javascript associated to that particular event from executing). However, unfortunately, the submission of the form itself, while possible to trigger and control via javascript, is not actually handled by javascript and is not a javascript function itself.

What I've found, in my experiences, to be the best solution, is to use the 'button' type input instead of the 'submit' type input - Both 'submit' and 'button' appear as buttons, but 'button' doesn't actually have any default inherent associated event action (therefore, doesn't actually do anything when you click on it) - What this means, is that, via event handlers (such as 'onclick', as you've done), you are able to entirely control what happens when a user clicks on a 'button'.

You haven't included your 'validateForm();' javascript function here, so I don't know what it contains, but, if it doesn't already do so, I'd include code to submit the form via that javascript function, submitting the form once validation has been successful (or returning some sort of human readable error if validation fails) - That combined with using 'button' instead of 'submit' should solve your problem.

Hope this helps. :)

Edit: Thought of this shortly after making my initial reply. Some browsers will process events handlers such as 'onclick' prior to submitting forms via the submit input type; However, I've found that certain older browsers do not do this currently (thus context of my above post). For newer browsers that honour the results of event handlers processed prior to form submission, it should be possible to prevent the second event (form submission) from occurring at all if validation fails; However, not all browsers honour these results, and I've found that some will continue to submit the form regardless of those results.

Comment: I usually just add the command "return false" to the end of the onClick javascript. That tells it not to submit the form under any circumstances. You can submit the form from within the validation function, if it passes.

Comment: What you're doing is correct, and should work, for the most part. I interpreted the phrasing of the topic question to mean, however, that the topic author is trying something similar already and it isn't working for him/her (thus my offering an alternative). However, I may be entirely incorrect in my interpretation - I'll have to wait and see how the topic author responds. :)

Comment: They tried putting "return false" in the onsubmit property of the form tag. I think by the time that fires, it's too late.

Comment: The validation will work if attached to the onsubmit as `return validateform()` and if it returns false if error. All browsers supports this.

Answer (score 0):

well thanks u all, so finally I found the solution by your ideas here is what I have done
rather putting return formvalidate(); function I put it in submit onclick event and it run like charm... thanks

```
<div style="margin-left: 55px;">
                    <input class="btn" style="width: 80px;" type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" onclick="clearFields()"/>
                    <input class="btn" style="width: 80px;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" onclick="return validateForm();"/>
                </div>
```

this is the javascript

```
function validateForm(){
    var form = document.forms['loginForm'];
    if(document.getElementById('loginName').value == "")
        document.getElementById('usernameError').innerHTML = 'Invalid username or email';
    else{
        form.submit();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is very wrong! Do not submit a form in a submit event. Please see my example in a minute.

Comment: When the submit button is clicked, the script is executed and the form submitted, then after the event, the form is submitted because you clicked a submit button. So the request is interrupting the submission process. EITHER change the submit button you have now to a type="button" OR use my answer as it stands. It is a vastly preferred way and will work on all browsers